# What is the exact statement of Hooke's law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, causality, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, linear-systems

The statement of [Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) states that STRESS is directly proportional to STRAIN. But if stress depends upon strain then strain must occur before stress comes into play. I am unable to understand how actually it happens when anything is applied a force upon.

Comment: If stress is proportional to strain, then they must happen *at the same time*, not one before the other.

Comment: Are you familiar with the stress tensor and the strain tensor?

Answer (score 1):

We can express Hooke's law mathematically as follows:

$$stress \propto strain$$

$$\frac{stress}{strain} = const$$

This constant is known as modulus of elasticity.

---

Stress is defined as force per unit area and strain is defined as change over actual value. Stress can cause strain (thermal stress) and strain can cause stress (stretching a string).

We will examine one case. When you pull a string,  you are applying a force, i.e: you are stressing the material. The string responds by stretching; this stretching is known as strain.

Mathematically, the stress and strain in this case is given by:

$$stress = \frac{F}{A}$$

$$strain = \frac{\Delta l}{l}$$

According to Hooke's law, the ratio of the two aforementioned quantities us constant. In this case(longitudinal stress), the constant is known as Young's Modulus.

Comment: Not sure if _"Stress... causes strain"_ is true. I believe the direction of causuality is ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, strain can be prevented. I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: I meant to say: I personally would avoid thinking which causes what. However, if you believe in strain/stress causation, then you should consider that strain can cause stress as well.

Comment: I too ignore thinking about the cause. The formulae work either way.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the spring is displaced from equilibrium by displacement $d$, there is a restoring force $-F_R$ towards the resting position. Hooke's Law only describes this restoring force $-F_R$. It doesn't describe external forces $F_E$.

Imagine you paused time (so the spring can't be displaced). When an external force $F_E$ is applied to the spring, you **tend** to displace the spring from equilibrium (but you haven't actually displaced the spring yet). This causes the spring to generate the restoring force $-F_R$ in the opposite direction of the **intended** displacement.

Now see what happens if you unpause time. An external force $F_E$ is applied to a spring at equilibrium. If $|F_E| > |F_R|$, the spring changes length with displacement $d$ proportional to $F_R$. If $|F_E| <= |F_R|$, the spring doesn't move.

Similar force analyses can be done for other starting positions of the spring (relative to the equilibrium position).

Comment: You have mentioned about two stresses. Sir can you please just explain about the external stresses. Because as per my understanding stress is only internal.

Comment: @RishavKumar You are right, I meant two forces. I'm removing that line to avoid confusion. The rest of the explanation still holds.